# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código para imprimir el contenido de una base de datos:

```
$k = $_POST['key'];
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM ltr WHERE letter_key= $k';
$ejecutar= $conexion->query($consulta);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)) {
    echo $row['letter'];
    echo $row['date'];
}
```

El problema es que ese código me arroja el error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Y no sé a qué se podría deber, ya que si modifico la consulta a:

```
'SELECT * FROM ltr'
```

No obtengo ningún error y el resultado se imprime por pantalla. ¿Podría ser que estoy haciendo la consulta de manera incorrecta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El error se debe a que mysqli::query devuelve FALSE en caso de que la consulta dé un error.
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

resaltado:

> El error se debe a que `mysqli::query` devuelve `FALSE` en caso de que la consulta dé un error.

- `FALSE` es un `boolean`
- `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` espera un `mysqli_result`

Tu consulta esta fallando porque no puedes añadir $k al string de forma implicita si usas comillas simples. **Debes usar comillas dobles.**

Ahora mismo le estas pidiendo a tu base de datos que te devuelva una letra cuya key es $k (literalmente, no el valor de $k).

De todos modos, añade una condición al código por si acaso:

```
$k = $_POST['key'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ltr WHERE letter_key = $k";
$ejecutar= $conexion->query($consulta);

if($ejecutar) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)) {
        echo $row['letter'];
        echo $row['date'];
    }
}
```

Recuerda tambien que si letter_key no es un INT, tendrás que rodear '$k' con comillas simples.

Comment: Es verdad, muchas gracias! No me había dado cuenta de las comillas.

Comment: Recuerda que es necesario escapar el parametro key recibido desde el cliente, para evitar ataques de inyeccion SQL. `$conexion->escape_string($k)`. Si el dato $k debe ser un entero. Entonces validar que de hecho lo sea.