# Al subir online este error: "......" expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Buen día. Estimados, por favor su valiosa ayuda y apoyo. Les comento. Estoy trabajando a modo aficionado un sistemita en PHP, uso servidor WAMP, y en modo local no tengo ningún problema. Al pasar el "sistema" a la web me da los siguientes errores al iniciar sesión:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /storage/ssd3/105/12138105/public_html/expedi/login.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /storage/ssd3/105/12138105/public_html/expedi/login.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/105/12138105/public_html/expedi/login.php:12) in /storage/ssd3/105/12138105/public_html/expedi/login.php on line 17

Como les digo, de modo local no tengo ningún problema y puedo accesar sin problema:
[image: Screenshot]

Como les digo, basandome en el error del servidor "online" les comparto mi código del archivo login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexion.php");

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$password = $_POST["contra"];


$sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$usuario' && password = '$password'";
$exe_logar = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_logar);
$fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);
$num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

if ($num_logar == 0){
   header("location: index.php?fallo=true");  
} 

else{
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
   $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    $_SESSION["nombres"] = $fet_logar["nombres"];
    $_SESSION["apellidos"] = $fet_logar["apellidos"];
    $_SESSION["t_usuario"] = $fet_logar["t_usuario"];
   header("Location:dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

Alguien me ayuda por favor? me pueden explicar porque de modo local si funciona y de modo "online" no? Les agradecere mucho.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warning: mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92000/warning-mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-g)

Comment: @BetaM gracias, pero no es el caso, mis comillas están bien declaradas.

Comment: en varias de las respuestas al mismo error, el error es siempre el mismo `mysqli_fetch_assoc` espera como parametro el resultado de una query, si la query falló ( `$exe_logar` en este caso ) da false, y es lo que dice el error: "espero un resultado de query y me estas dando un booleano"

Comment: @aloMalbarez entiendo que es la consulta "falsa" pero al pasar mi codigo de `$exe_logar` a la consulta en SQL no me da error:
`MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas). (La consulta tardó 0,0002 segundos.)
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$usuario' && password = '$password'`

Comment: chequea la [versión de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html) "The &&, operator is a nonstandard MySQL extension. As of MySQL 8.0.17, this operator is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future MySQL version. Applications should be adjusted to use the standard SQL AND operator."

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al problema de los headers intenta poner al inicio del código ob_start(); y al final ob_end_flush();

Estas etiquetas permiten enviar los headers en cualquier lugar del documento.
Y cuidar espacios en blanco al abrir o cerrar las etiquetas de php.

Comment: Convendría agregues el fin de usar duchas etiquetas, es decir ¿Por qué son la solución al ptoblema?

Comment: manipular el output buffer no tendría mucho efecto pues el error/warning está siendo impreso justo antes del header location